# Take value from field in Form to a new record in other Table

Tags: forms, ms-access, field, record

Would really like some guidance on this one. Not as easy as the title might say at first and I'm stuck beyond all and frustrated.

So:

- I have a MainForm (With a current ID I would like to stay on!)
- I have a Subform (search engine that searches in various linked excel files)
- I have 2 tables; one for the Mainform, and one for Items

So on the Mainform, I display the Subform (search).
I do my search and find a specific item in the excel files
I have a command button, that I want to click save the found item in the search field, into my ItemsTable as a new record.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
Private Sub Command13_Click()
Forms!MainForm.Form.Item1.Value = Me.Searchresult.Value
End Sub
```

This does actually post my search result into a new field and saves it into the itemsTable.

My problem: I don't need to actually have a field to post to. I just want it to write directly to my table and store it there as a NEW record. (Right now it just overwrites the previous data. Logically because its the same field every time with the same properties).

Can someone PLEASE help me with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. set focus to the subform container then move to New Record row followed by your code, this is not simple, review https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=127337
2. use SQL INSERT action then requery the subform
   `CurrentDb.Execute("INSERT INTO Items(Item1) VALUES('" & Me.Searchresult & "'")`